# JqueryMobile multiple datepicker in a popup doesn't work on IE

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui, internet-explorer, jquery-mobile

I'm facing an issue when trying to use jQuery mobile datepicker on input `type="date"` on Internet Explorer for windows phone.

I load the datepickers by using the Modernizr library like this :

```
Modernizr.load({
 test: Modernizr.inputtypes.date,
  nope: ["../datepicker/js/jquery-ui-1.10.3.custom.js", "../datepicker/js/localizations/jquery.ui.datepicker-fr.js"],
   callback: function () {                
    $("head").append("<link rel='stylesheet' type='text/css' href='../datepicker/css/jquery-ui-1.10.3.custom.css'/>");
    $("input[type=date]").datepicker({ minDate: "+0d" });
   }
});
```

This code create an instance of datepicker for each input `type=date` in my code if the browser cannot handle them. And it works fine actually ! But there is one case which i can't understand.

On my application, i have a jQuery Mobile popup (div with `data-role="popup"`) which contains two input `type="date"`. When the popup opens, my two inputs have their own datepicker which opens when the input got the focus. But there is the problem. The click on the first date input, datepicker opens itself, and i can select a date fine. Then i want to select the second date, datepicker opens and then, when i select a date in this datepicker, the focus switch back on the first date input, opens the first datepicker and doesn't select any date on my second datepicker.

I tried to put a dedicated id on each on my inputs and create datepickers by targeting those id, but with the same results :/

Hope you guys can understand the problem i expose. And i hope you can help me.

Comment: can you reproduce this case on [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/)?

Comment: i tried to reproduce my problem on jsfiddle but can't make it happens. Works fine on js fiddle. So the problem is from something else in my code. I'll try to figure it out.

Comment: but it happens only on IE, other browsers work fine, right?

Comment: All browsers works fine. It works allright on IE 8 as well, but IE 7, 9, 10 and mobile version does not work. I'm suspecting some function override in the js file jquery-ui-1.10.3.custom.js i'm loading which are causing this. I'm now trying to load the datepicker elements only and see what happens then.

Comment: This [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/7bbukx2v/) illustrates the problem.

Comment: [Live example](http://www.elitesystemer.no/misc/testrapport.php)
Same behaviour in IE, Firefox, Chrome and Opera

Answer (score 0):

Can you try with DateRange Method.

http://jqueryui.com/datepicker/#date-range

Comment: I get the same misbehaviour with the DateRange method.